# Accessing an element of an array of objects of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays

I have read and understand why accessing an element of, for example, ints takes O(1) time, since we know the size of an int. However, say that we have a struct

```
struct Foo{
   int array[];
}
```

and then create an array of Foo, `Foo foo_array[]`. Will it still take O(1) time to access an element in `foo_array`? In this case, the size of each element in `foo_array` might be of different, so my guess is that it will not take O(1) time. However, since `array` in `Foo` can be viewed as a pointer, maybe Foo has constant size?

Comment: You can't create an array with variable-size elements in C.

Comment: If the array is of an unknown size, you never know if the index you use is valid, i.e. if you are doing a valid access. So the size must be known somehow, somewhere. There is no way around that. And arrays only store items of the same size. Not sure what you are asking, but what you want doesn't work. You could have an array of (equally sized) pointers to items of different sizes, though. So start thinking about pointers.

Comment: `Foo foo_array[]` ==> `struct Foo foo_array[]`. "Maybe `Foo` has constant size?" Its size is fixed by the data you initialise it with at the point of definition. `int array[];` and `Foo foo_array[]` are not proper definitions.

Comment: I did not know that you can't create an array with variable-size elements in C. So insteas, one has to create an array of pointers, `Foo * foo_array[]`? How does C++ vectors handle element accessing, because there you could create `vector<Foo> foo_vector` (i think).

Comment: How would you create an array of `Foo` exactly? How many bytes do you think that would allocate?

Comment: You can create a local array in C with variable number of elements, but C11 made that optional. You have to **define** the number of elements, and empty brackets `[]` don't do that, unless the data is provided at the point of definition, such as `int array[] = { 1 , 2 };`